# How to add read more or less button in table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

What is best way to achieve this below?

Suppose my front end table look like this:

```
id  | usernname | role url
 1  | JHON      | /welcome... readmore
```

On initial load it should show just one url, but when the user clicks on read more then role url show all data like this:

```
id  | usernname | role url
 1  | JHON      | /welcome ,/addnew ,/product, /purchase
```

Is there any good way to achieve this? **Note** this role url can contain more url  i.e. it is dynamically increasing.

Comment: datatable just shows data from your server ,you can configure the this thing in your server data and use javascript to make an event ,like clicking on read more

Comment: @JaiDixit can i do it in client side because database does not contain more than 500 record in future

Comment: you can configure which column ,to show or hide but I guess what you are looking is not supported in datatable ,like you can't manipulate data for particular column

Comment: which language you are using at your server side??

Comment: @JaiDixit node and i don't want to manupulate data just hide or show data according to click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example below shows how you can add a click event to a span within the URL cell. This then toggles a class within the parent cell which shows/hides the URLs depending on the current state. This relies on you loading two spans, one with the condensed URLs, and one with all the URLs.

I've added some styling to help the user understand the interactivity.

**Alternative** - instead of loading two spans (which needs you to add /welcome twice), you can create a span with just class `.long` with the extra URLs. This is demonstrated in row 2 with username b.date.

**Update:** added a button that starts a timeout to show dynamically adding URLs, if you add a URL you should add a class to the parent `td` so that it knows it has multiple URLs, this will let you show the show more/less link. It adds it using the unique row `id` that I have added.

Let me know if this isn't what you wanted.

```js
// Add click event to each element with class toggle-more
// This is dynamic, so will work on any new 'show more'
$('#user-list').on('click', '.toggle-more', function(){

  // toggle 'more' class in the closest parent table cell
  $(this).closest("td").toggleClass("more");

  // Change text of link
  if ($(this).text() == "show more") {
    $(this).text("show less");
  } else {
    $(this).text("show more");
  }

});


// Click event to start adding URLs
$("#addURL").click( function() {
  addURL();
  $(this).remove();
});


// Add a new URL
function addURL() {

  // Add a new URL, you will have to select the appropriate row in real use - i.e. replace #user-1 with a unique row identifier
  $("#user-1 .url-list .toggle-more").before("<span class='url long'> ,/newURL</span>");
  
  // Add a class to the table cell so we know there are multiple URLs, again you will need to replace #user-1 with your unique row identifier. 
  $("#user-1 .url-list").addClass("multi-url");
  
  // Continue adding URLs
  var addURLtimer = setTimeout(addURL, 3000);
  
}
```

```css
td .long {
  display: none;
}

td.more .long {
  display: inherit;
}

td.more .short {
  display: none;
}

.url, .toggle-more {
float: left;
}

.url {
padding-left: 4px;
}

.toggle-more {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 4px;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.multi-url .toggle-more {
 display: inherit;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th, td {
padding: 4px;
text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="user-list">

  <tr>
    <th>
      id
    </th>
    <th>
      username
    </th>
    <th>
      role url
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr id="user-0">
    <td>
      0
    </td>
    <td>
      j.smith
    </td>
    <td class="url-list multi-url">
      <span class="short url">/ welcome</span>
      <span class="long url"> /welcome ,/addnew ,/product, /purchase</span> <a class="toggle-more">show more</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="user-1">
    <td>
      1
    </td>
    <td>
      b.times
    </td>
    <td class="url-list">
      <span class="url">/ welcome</span>
      <span class="toggle-more">show more</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>


<button id="addURL">Start Adding URLs</button>
```

Comment: thanks for you time on initial load i just want to show /welcome (this column not just contain /welcome it dynamically increasing according to database for eg :- it contain like /welcome ,/addnew ,/product, /purchase ...n it just  want to take first string and show + readmore )and readmore option

Comment: same thing i want but problem is that role url may or may not contain url more over it does not contain fixed length of role url it increaing according to database entry

Comment: Updated for the requested functionality.